# Using incremental inside loop not return expected results

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking for a solution to create a sequencial counter for my nested loop. So I made this test:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in list" :key="item">{{ counter++ }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Foo",
  data() {
    return {
      list: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
      counter: 0
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

But instead return 1,2,3, it return 303, 304, 305 and this warning:

> You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

I known that I can use `(item, index)`. But I have a nested loop in real code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-mcnulty-hou4p

This is the real situation nested loop:

```
<template v-for="ranking in daysImages[currentDay]['images']">
    <template v-for="image in ranking">
        <figure class="thumb"
            v-for="path in image.paths"
            :key="path"
            @click="openModal()"
            v-show="
            (selectHashTag === allHashTagsTitle || image['hashtags'].includes(selectHashTag)) &&
            (selectTag === allTagsTitle || image['tags'].includes(selectTag))"
        >
            <img :src="path | formatImageURL" alt="">
        </figure>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Please let us see the real code, and let us know why you can't use `(item, index)`, since a nested loop shouldn't break it. The loop appears because you're doing `counter++` in the actual rendering.

Comment: And where do you want to use the index in that those 3 loops?

Comment: @Djip I need to store index inside a `data-index` attribute in `<figure>` tag

Comment: But which index? Index of ranking, image or path? I guess you don't need all 3 in one attribute right?

Comment: @Djip Index for total image sequence. That's why I can't use `(ranking, index)`, `(image, index)` or `(path, index)`. None of them consider the entire loop.

Comment: @marcelo2605 just add `:data-index="index"` or add `:data-index="index-image.length"` for example.. whatever you need, or if there is math involved use custom method

Comment: how do you define which counter should be associated to which item? For now it seems you say: when I plot an item the counter increases (which btw creates an infinite loop because when you plot you increase the counter, so vue rerenders, then you reinc the counter and so on...)

Comment: @grodzi The loop is using a multidimensional object. That' why I need to use nested loop. The result is a sequence of `<figure>` and I need to add for each of them it number position based on entire list.

Comment: Try this:  <li v-for="(value, key) in list" :key="key">{{ parseInt(counter) + key + 1 }}</li>

Comment: @AnkurMishra It works. But I can't depend on the `key` value.

Comment: @marcelo2605 I know your concern. I am checking this.

Comment: Can't you just map your 2d to a 1d array? Also does each ranking contain the same number of images?

Comment: @grodzi Nope. They may have differents number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `counter++` which increments it after each render, maybe you could use `.indexOf(item)` on your array to get the actual index of the item without using the Vue stuff ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I can't deppend on loop object

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with either using a non reactive property, or simply defining an index on each item before render:

For the latter:

- You may flatMap your 2d array to 1d array (and you trivially access the id by its position in the array)
- You can compute the id your self and assign it to every element, then render your grid as usual.

```js
let Grid = {
    props: ['arr2d'],
    data () {
      return {
        arr1d: this.arr2d.flatMap(x=>x)
      }
    },
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(fruit, counter) in arr1d">
          {{fruit}}: {{counter}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    `
  }
  let Grid2 = {
    props: ['arr2d'],
    data () {
      let z = 0
      return {
        indexedArray: this.arr2d.map((ranking, i) => {
          return ranking.map(im => {
            return { image: im, id: z++ }
          })
        })
      }
    },
    template: `
      <ul>
        <template v-for="ranking in indexedArray">
          <template v-for="({image, id}) in ranking">
            <li>{{image}}: {{ id }}</li>
          </template>
        </template>
      </ul>
    `
  }
  new Vue({
    components:{ Grid, Grid2 },
    template: `<div>
      <Grid :arr2d="[['apple','grodzi', 'orange'], ['lime', 'lemon']]"/>
      <Grid2 :arr2d="[['apple','grodzi', 'orange'], ['lime', 'lemon']]"/>
    </div>`,
    el:'#app'
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```